# Symfony2: Class declarations may not be nested in FatalErrorException.php

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

When I get a fatal error in my Symfony 2.3.7 project I get a blank page and not a symfony error page in my dev-environment.

When I check the error-log of the server I can see the error that caused the fatal error and another error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class declarations may not be nested in
>   /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php
>   on line 20

I have no idea what could cause this behavior. This is a normal, standard Symfony2 installation.

I 've updated my vendors, cleared the cache multiple times, ... but I can't seem to find the problem.

Has anybody experienced this before or have a clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Blank screens in development often mean that you are actually crashing the php interpreter.  I did this once using empty($obj->getSomething());  Took some time to figure it out.  Is it a completely new S2.3.7 project that is crashing on acmedemo?  Or have you added code to it?

Comment: No, there is a lot of code in it. At first this wasn't the case. I meant that it the vendors are all up to date and nothing was changed there, as it should be.

Comment: Ok.  xdebug might help.  Otherwise, it's more of a file by file thing.  Maybe start with a fresh project and then add stuff until it breaks.  Did it work under 2.3.6?

Comment: This could be a syntax error in your bootstrap file.  Delete the vendors directory, the bootstrap file, your cache, then run composer install.

Comment: Flosculus, this was my first thought as well, but it turned out to be a mistake in my app_dev.php file.